# new \DateTime() gives the same value for multiple requests

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have used the following piece of code in some APIs to limit the request

```
sleep(1);
// date_value_from_db is taken from DB, question time as example
$date_value_from_db = '2022-12-31 11:18:00Z';
$lastCreatedAt = new DateTime($date_value_from_db);
$now = new \DateTime();
#echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$timeElapsedInSecs = $now->getTimestamp() - $lastCreatedAt->getTimestamp();

// Only execute if the time difference is more than 60 secs
if ($timeElapsedInSecs < 60) {
    // throw Exception
}

// Proceed further
```

If you call this API in a loop, `$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` returns the same value 3-4 times in a row, after that, it shows the correct current time. and so on. For example `echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` in the above code looks like this:

```
2022-12-30 11:30:25
2022-12-30 11:30:25
2022-12-30 11:30:25
2022-12-30 11:31:32
2022-12-30 11:31:32
...
```

Also, the `$timeElapsedInSecs` value is also the same

Ideally, `$now` should give the current time for each call. But it's not happening.
Do you guys see any issues with the above code?

Comment: the request approaches in the very same second... which is not unusual for a web application

Comment: when you say that it returns the same value some times in a row before hitting the correct one what do you exactly mean? the fact you get the same value maybe it's just because the request are done in the same second time span. But I'm not sure what you meant saying _"correct current time"_ compared to the uncorrect

Comment: Note that, I also have used `sleep(1)`.

Comment: Please share where/what/how `'date-value-from-db'` is, because  `new DateTime('date-value-from-db');` is not valid PHP

Comment: @Luuk - Here the main concern is why `$now = new \DateTime();` gives the same value if you mass execute the above script.

Answer (score 1):

I created a file name `testdt.php` on my local system like this:

```
<?php
$now = new \DateTime();
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
```

When executing this script 100 time (I am on Windows) using:

```
for /L %f in (1,1,100) do @curl "http://localhost/test/testdt.php"
```

I do see the returned value change.

When you need more change, you should change 'Y-m-d H:i:s' to 'Y-m-d H:i:s.v', this will add milli-seconds

Comment: Is there a way to make a call at the same time (maybe using some tool)? I think something wrong with the call

Comment: @MagePsycho: I did read your comment multiple times, but I am afraid I do not understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I feel that issue is not with the code but that someone is trying to call the API from different locations/scripts at the same time.

Comment: But, also then, `$now = new \DateTime();` should (and will) give you a new DateTime with the value of the current date/time.  If that was not true, then....  a lot of websites would have troubles...